# How to rotate a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to rotate a `CAShapeLayer` with respect to a particular anchor point. But when i apply 
`firstLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_2_PI), 0, 0, 0)`
nothing happens.

i am making a custom `UIButton` , in which i am adding a layer

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class CustomButtonTwo: UIButton {
var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
@IBInspectable var Thickness : CGFloat = 2

let firstLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var width = CGFloat()
var height = CGFloat()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    width = self.frame.width
    height = self.frame.height
    print("\(width) : \(height)")
}
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    let afirstStartPoint = CGPointMake(width * 0.1, (height - 3 * Thickness) / 6)
    let bfirstStartPoint = CGPointMake(width * 0.1, (height - 3 * Thickness) / 6 + Thickness)
    let afirstMiddlePoint = CGPointMake(width * 0.5, (height - 3 * Thickness) / 6 )
    let bfirstMiddlePoint = CGPointMake(width * 0.5, (height - 3 * Thickness) / 6 + Thickness)
    print(afirstMiddlePoint)
    print(afirstStartPoint)
    print(bfirstMiddlePoint)
    print(bfirstStartPoint)
    let firstPath = UIBezierPath()
    firstPath.moveToPoint(afirstStartPoint)
    firstPath.addLineToPoint(afirstMiddlePoint)
    firstPath.addLineToPoint(bfirstMiddlePoint)
    firstPath.addLineToPoint(bfirstStartPoint)
    firstPath.addLineToPoint(afirstStartPoint)
    firstPath.closePath()
    firstLayer.frame = self.frame
    UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
    firstPath.fill()

    firstLayer.path = firstPath.CGPath
    firstLayer.anchorPoint = afirstStartPoint
    firstLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_2_PI), 0, 0, 1)
     layer.addSublayer(firstLayer)
}



}
```

i want to make a line with a particular thickness and rotate it along a particular point (while animating).
any help appreciated!

[simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0sCy.png)

Comment: If you are going to add sub layers try overriding `layoutSubviews()` instead of `drawRect()`

Answer (score 1):

Rotating by `2_PI (360)` will mean layer will end up back at its original place (0 rotation). Try `PI_2 (90)` or `PI (180)` or another angle. Also you need to specify the axis of rotation.

This call rotates by 90 degrees around z-axis:

```
CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0, 0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Your first sentence is not accurate. A layer starts on 0.0 radian so 2 * pi will surely give full rotation.

Comment: @Desdenova yes i fixed that , i also achieved what i was looking for, via UIView, but i am still curious about how can we achieve that with a CAShapeLayer!

Comment: @AchintyaGupta Not in drawRect like that.